# Dividing rows into several ones if multiple elements are stored in one column

Tags: r

I have a data frame similar to this, only longer:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  `First name` `Last name` Username   TwitterID    Party                             Chamber Country `Legislative per… Notes
  <chr>        <chr>       <chr>      <chr>        <chr>                             <chr>   <chr>   <chr>             <chr>
1 Raynell      Andreychuk  SenAndrey… 902575098    "Conservative Party of Canada (2… Senate  Canada  1993/03/11 - 201… NA   
2 Salma        Ataullahjan SenatorSa… 498059173    "Conservative Party of Canada (2… Senate  Canada  2010/07/09 -      NA   
3 Michèle      Audette     michele_a… 948136886    "Independent Senators Group (202… Senate  Canada  2021/07/29 -      NA   
4 Denise       Batters     denisebat… 2422634642   "Conservative Party of Canada (2… Senate  Canada  2013/01/25 -      NA   
5 Diane        Bellemare   sendbelle… 1426402920   "\"Canadian Senators Group (2019… Senate  Canada  2012/09/06 -      NA   
6 Wanda Thomas Bernard     SenatorWa… 83161013426… "Progressive Senate Group (2020/… Senate  Canada  2016/11/10 -      NA
```

My goal is, to divide each row into a new row whenever the politician is active in a new party (see [party]). I've tried my luck with an `ifelse()` but without any success. I greatly appreciate any help I can get!

For reproducibility:

```
structure(list(`First name` = c("Raynell", "Salma", "Michèle", 
"Denise", "Diane", "Wanda Thomas"), `Last name` = c("Andreychuk", 
"Ataullahjan", "Audette", "Batters", "Bellemare", "Bernard"), 
    Username = c("SenAndreychuk", "SenatorSalma", "michele_audette", 
    "denisebatters", "sendbellemare", "SenatorWanda"), TwitterID = c("902575098", 
    "498059173", "948136886", "2422634642", "1426402920", "831610134262665216"
    ), Party = c("Conservative Party of Canada (2004/02/02 - 2019/08/13)\r\r\nProgressive Conservative Party (1993/03/11 - 2004/02/01)", 
    "Conservative Party of Canada (2010/07/09 - )", "Independent Senators Group (2021/09/27 - )\r\r\nNon-affiliated (2021/07/29 - 2021/09/26)", 
    "Conservative Party of Canada (2013/01/25 - )", "\"Canadian Senators Group (2019/11/04 - )\r\nIndependent Senators Group (2018/02/28 - 2019/11/03)\r\nNon-affiliated (2018/02/15 - 2018/02/27)\"", 
    "Progressive Senate Group (2020/07/08 - )\r\r\nIndependent Senators Group (2017/06/01 - 2020/07/07)\r\r\nNon-affiliated (Independent Senators Group) (2017/03/30 - 2017/05/31)\r\r\nNon-affiliated (2016/11/10 - 2017/03/29)"
    ), Chamber = c("Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", 
    "Senate"), Country = c("Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
    "Canada", "Canada"), `Legislative period` = c("1993/03/11 - 2019/08/13", 
    "2010/07/09 -", "2021/07/29 -", "2013/01/25 -", "2012/09/06 -", 
    "2016/11/10 -"), Notes = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `tidyr::separate_rows(Party, sep = "[\r\n]")`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data <-
  structure(list(
    `First name` = c(
      "Raynell", "Salma", "Michèle",
      "Denise", "Diane", "Wanda Thomas"
    ), `Last name` = c(
      "Andreychuk",
      "Ataullahjan", "Audette", "Batters", "Bellemare", "Bernard"
    ),
    Username = c(
      "SenAndreychuk", "SenatorSalma", "michele_audette",
      "denisebatters", "sendbellemare", "SenatorWanda"
    ), TwitterID = c(
      "902575098",
      "498059173", "948136886", "2422634642", "1426402920", "831610134262665216"
    ), Party = c(
      "Conservative Party of Canada (2004/02/02 - 2019/08/13)\r\r\nProgressive Conservative Party (1993/03/11 - 2004/02/01)",
      "Conservative Party of Canada (2010/07/09 - )", "Independent Senators Group (2021/09/27 - )\r\r\nNon-affiliated (2021/07/29 - 2021/09/26)",
      "Conservative Party of Canada (2013/01/25 - )", "\"Canadian Senators Group (2019/11/04 - )\r\nIndependent Senators Group (2018/02/28 - 2019/11/03)\r\nNon-affiliated (2018/02/15 - 2018/02/27)\"",
      "Progressive Senate Group (2020/07/08 - )\r\r\nIndependent Senators Group (2017/06/01 - 2020/07/07)\r\r\nNon-affiliated (Independent Senators Group) (2017/03/30 - 2017/05/31)\r\r\nNon-affiliated (2016/11/10 - 2017/03/29)"
    ), Chamber = c(
      "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate", "Senate",
      "Senate"
    ), Country = c(
      "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada",
      "Canada", "Canada"
    ), `Legislative period` = c(
      "1993/03/11 - 2019/08/13",
      "2010/07/09 -", "2021/07/29 -", "2013/01/25 -", "2012/09/06 -",
      "2016/11/10 -"
    ), Notes = c(
      "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA",
      "NA"
    )
  ), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c(
    "tbl_df", "tbl",
    "data.frame"
  ))
data
#> # A tibble: 6 x 9
#>   `First name` `Last name` Username   TwitterID  Party           Chamber Country
#>   <chr>        <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      <chr>           <chr>   <chr>  
#> 1 Raynell      Andreychuk  SenAndrey… 902575098  "Conservative … Senate  Canada 
#> 2 Salma        Ataullahjan SenatorSa… 498059173  "Conservative … Senate  Canada 
#> 3 Michèle      Audette     michele_a… 948136886  "Independent S… Senate  Canada 
#> 4 Denise       Batters     denisebat… 2422634642 "Conservative … Senate  Canada 
#> 5 Diane        Bellemare   sendbelle… 1426402920 "\"Canadian Se… Senate  Canada 
#> 6 Wanda Thomas Bernard     SenatorWa… 831610134… "Progressive S… Senate  Canada 
#> # … with 2 more variables: Legislative period <chr>, Notes <chr>
data %>%
  separate_rows(Party, sep = "[\r\n]") %>%
  filter(Party != "")
#> # A tibble: 13 x 9
#>    `First name` `Last name` Username   TwitterID  Party          Chamber Country
#>    <chr>        <chr>       <chr>      <chr>      <chr>          <chr>   <chr>  
#>  1 Raynell      Andreychuk  SenAndrey… 902575098  "Conservative… Senate  Canada 
#>  2 Raynell      Andreychuk  SenAndrey… 902575098  "Progressive … Senate  Canada 
#>  3 Salma        Ataullahjan SenatorSa… 498059173  "Conservative… Senate  Canada 
#>  4 Michèle      Audette     michele_a… 948136886  "Independent … Senate  Canada 
#>  5 Michèle      Audette     michele_a… 948136886  "Non-affiliat… Senate  Canada 
#>  6 Denise       Batters     denisebat… 2422634642 "Conservative… Senate  Canada 
#>  7 Diane        Bellemare   sendbelle… 1426402920 "\"Canadian S… Senate  Canada 
#>  8 Diane        Bellemare   sendbelle… 1426402920 "Independent … Senate  Canada 
#>  9 Diane        Bellemare   sendbelle… 1426402920 "Non-affiliat… Senate  Canada 
#> 10 Wanda Thomas Bernard     SenatorWa… 831610134… "Progressive … Senate  Canada 
#> 11 Wanda Thomas Bernard     SenatorWa… 831610134… "Independent … Senate  Canada 
#> 12 Wanda Thomas Bernard     SenatorWa… 831610134… "Non-affiliat… Senate  Canada 
#> 13 Wanda Thomas Bernard     SenatorWa… 831610134… "Non-affiliat… Senate  Canada 
#> # … with 2 more variables: Legislative period <chr>, Notes <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>